# Using flask for Spyder [ No module named 'flask']

Tags: python, flask, spyder

I have flask install by

```
conda install flask
pip install flask
```

While I type flask in the terminal, it works.
While I type conda list, it appears on the list.

```
flask                     1.0.2                    py36_1
```

However, it pops up  [ No module named 'flask'] while I run it on the spyder with tensorflow. How should I solve it?

**Upgrade:
Solved. The problem was I ran spyder in virtualenv which didn't include flask module on it.**

Answer (score 0):

It could be that tensorflow is trying to use a different version of python (2.7) which doesn't have flask installed.

You can either try and install flask with a version of pip linked to python 2.7 or get tensorflow to use the version of python which your pip installed flask to (seems like 3.6).

You can use the which command to try and see which version is being called and debug from there.

```
which pip
which pip3
which python
which python3
```

But basically, pip is linked to a specific version of python. Since systems come with 2.7 installed by default but you then install 3.6 after, you end up having two different package managers (pip and pip3). The modules that they install only work for their specific version of python. This could be the root of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In spyder python 3.7.6 version, I just run:

```
from flask import Flask
```

and it executed.

So no need to install flask in spyder, because it already has it installed.